# How to use VLOOKUP in this situation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Here's what I'm trying to do with no success.
I have 2 sheets in a workbook. Format and TC.
Format looks something like this:
[image]

And TC looks something like this
[image]

I want to add after the last column in Format another column where to add the values that are in the 10th column of the TC value. That if the 2nd columns in both are the same.
This is how I tried to do it and it seems it doesn't work and I really don't know why since I'm an absolute beginer with VLOOKUP.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(B2;TC!B:B;TC!V:V;FALSE)= "Montaj (Montage)"; "here I want to select the time and I don't know how…"; "VALUE NOT FOUND")
```

To explain it better... if the value of one cell in column 2(B) in the Format sheet is found in TC sheet in column 2(or B) then if the value of the 4th column (V) is "Montaj (Montage)" I want to put the value in the 10th column (235 in the example).
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FINAL UPDATE: Added explanation.**

What you need is SUMIFS. I fixed this to match your comment below.

```
=SUMIFS(TC!Z:Z,TC!B:B,Format!B2,TC!J:J,"Montaj (Montage)")
```

This will look in the B column in the TC sheet and look for the value in B2 of the Format sheet. If it finds it, AND it finds "Montaj (Montage)" in the same row in the J column, then it will return(sum if there are more than one match) value in the SAME ROW in the J column.

SUMIF is really convenient for summing conditions like this. If you only have 1 condition, you can use SUMIF. VLookup is similar, but it just returns a single value, it doesn't do anything with it.

Here is some helpful info on how SUMIFS works: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it's not SUMIF what I'm looking for. If I use SUMIF it will SUM all the values in the column J (or Z or whatever I put there) if the condition is true... and the condition will be true for many times. What I want to do is. If (the value in B column is the same with the value in B column of TC) AND (the value of let's say J column is "Montaj (Montage)") THEN I want to add in this cell the value of column Z and just the value of column Z

Comment: I added more details. To give you an example. If the value in Format is Z-575844.01.VA and it's found in TC's B column than I want to check if the value of J column is "Montaj (Montage)" and if it is then I want to get the value in Z column (which in this case is 235).

Comment: All fixed! Try out the new formula!

Comment: Thanks again but I don't want to SUM the values... I want to return just 1 value. Also it has to search on the entire B column of TC because the values there are not in the same order as in the column B of Format. I gave you a vote up because SUMIF is an interesting function too and I didn't knew about it but what I need here is Vlookup. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I reverted the code to what it was and added a better explanation. Try it out. The SUMIF looks like it'll sum all the Z row if the 2 conditions are true, but that's not what happens. It just sums the corresponding Z column value in cases where the B column matches the B2 value in Format AND the J cell in that same row is that string you want.

Comment: This new code should be exactly what you want. The only case in which there will be more than 1 value found in Z is if there is more than one case of a row in B that matches "Z-575844.01.VA" and has "Montaj (Montage)" in the same row in the J column.

Comment: =IF(VLOOKUP(B3;TC!$B$2:$Z$220;21;FALSE)="Montaj (Montage)";VLOOKUP(B3;TC!$B$2:$Z$220;25;FALSE);0) I did something like this... and it worked. Anyway thanks a lot for your help because I'll need something like in your answer later on in the application